# Connecting QML and Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

So here is my complicated question and I hope you know the answer :)

I am developing app for android using Qt Necessitas. 
I have made `.ui` file for GUI and I didn't find it what I really want so a lot of people suggested QML as it is very dynamic and a lot of options available.

But problem to me is as I have never been working with QML before.

I need a bit of help just with few functions so I can know how to do it later.

For example. this is my function which I call it to read data from database using a post method and calling php script.

```
void MainWindow::Citanje_korisnika()  //read users
{
    init();
    QUrl params;
    params.addQueryItem("action","Citanje_korisnika");
    QByteArray data;
    data.append(params.toString());
    data.remove(0,1);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
    QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    reply = manager->post(request, data);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),this, SLOT(updateDataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)));
}
```

1. So my question is how to call this function from qml code? For example when user presses button?
2. After that I have this function which puts me everything into my form.

   ```
   void MainWindow::Pokazi(QList< QMap<QString,QString> >& osobe)  //show
   {
       i_max=osobe.count();
       osobe_next=osobe;
       osoba = osobe.at(0);
       //trenutni_id=osoba["id"];
       ui->label_ID->setText(osoba["id"]);
       ui->line_ime->insert(osoba["ime"]);
       ui->line_prezime->insert(osoba["prezime"]);
       ui->line_telefon->insert(osoba["broj"]);
       ui->line_adresa->insert(osoba["adresa"]);
   }
   ```

So this is where I want to display all persons on my list.

1. Is it possible to load this above QList into QML ListView which looks like this?
   Can I populate it dynamically?

   ```
   ListModel {
       ListElement {
           name: "Bill Smith"
           number: "555 3264"
       }
       ListElement {
           name: "John Brown"
           number: "555 8426"
       }
   }
   ```

This is only example with already inserted values. My question is how to make it populate from qml code dynamically?

And I want to get my list looks like second picture in this link: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-listview.html

I managed to make it looks like this but problem is I want to load my data dynamically inside I don't want it predefined.

If you need more code let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) calling c++ function from QML is easy. 
 You need to expose your object via setContextProperty
 QDeclarativeContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
 ctxt->setContextProperty("timer", &timerObj);

Then you can call any slots of exposed object or function which is declated as Q_INVOKABLE.

[This link](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2011/04/signal-slot-connection-with-qml-and-qt.html) may help you more.

2) You need to create model, you can use [QStringListModel](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QStringListModel.html), or you can create custom model derived from [QAbstractListModel](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractlistmodel.html).

Hope this will help you.